# LAMP server, website not displaying correctly on host

Tags: html, linux, wordpress, localhost, virtualbox

I'm pretty new to LAMP and web design in general, so please excuse any obvious mistakes I may be making.

I have setup a LAMP server on my Linux (Ubuntu) virtual machine and proceeded to install Wordpress.  Everything is working fine when I access via the virtual machine.

However, when I access my Wordpress site via the host machine (Windows), it seems to be lacking any styling.  The HTML seems to be rendering fine, but nothing else.

Here is screenshot of how the Wordpress page is displaying on my host system-

[image]

Any ideas what is causing this behavior?  Thank you!

Comment: have you checked the `home` and `sitelurl` fields in your `wp_options` table ?

Comment: stylesheet isnt found, thats all, check your paths and make sure the it's linking to your stylesheet properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can provide us the folder structures of your WordPress template and CSS?

Can you also view page source of the webpage and check the current CSS path that the template is pointing to?

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I realized my mistake as soon as I looked at the page source again this morning. My site was setup with the address as "localhost", which obviously would point to the wrong place when viewing from my host machine. I instead changed it to a static local IP address and now it works just fine

Comment: You are most welcome. I always do that to check the path if it is wrong. Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your web server is communicating with the database which is definitely a good sign. What's causing the behavior is that the link to style.css isn't configured correctly. Could be file permissions if your using the theme that WP comes with otherwise it could be permalinks or a broken link in the theme.

If your just looking to set up a site locally for development I would recommend using WAMP (pc) or MAMP (mac). A VM is a little overkill and CPU intense if your running Illustrator and Photoshop at the same time.

WAMP http://www.wampserver.com/en/
MAMP http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html